# VK API Сборщик близких человека. Порекомендуйте с чего начать

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подскажите материал или язык программирования который необходим для этой задумки.
Нужно создать программу с API VK. 
Она должна уметь:
Собирать базу максимально близких друзей человека по id VK. Это могут быть люди которые указанны как родные/лучшие друзья/коллеги.

Comment: Начать порекомендую с изучения программирования и любого распространенного языка общего назначения.

Comment: http://turbo-basic.narod.ru/ рекомендую, отличный язык для первых шагов